# JSON.NET and Gson bad interaction

Tags: c#, android, json

I am connecting an adroid client with a c# server. To serialize the information I decided to use json. On the c# side is JSON.NET lib, on the android one is Gson lib.

When I serialize my object from the server I obtain this output that seems ok to me:

```
{
  "Num_comunidad": "999",
  "Num_propietario": "0",
  "Nif": "123456789Q",
  "Razon": "BENITO TOCAMELA UNRATO",
  "Nombre": "",
  "Via": "",
  "Calle": "",
  "Num_calle": "0",
  "Piso": "",
  "Resto_domi": "",
  "Cod_pos": "00000",
  "Poblacion": "",
  "Provincia": "",
  "Tel1": "",
  "Tel2": "",
  "Tel3": "",
  "Fax": ""
}
```

When I check the android log, the received string is:

```
12-28 20:10:25.799: I/System.out(1411): ########INPUT STRING: {

12-28 20:10:25.799: I/System.out(1411):   "Num_comunidad": "999",

12-28 20:10:25.809: I/System.out(1411):   "Num_propietario": "0",

12-28 20:10:25.809: I/System.out(1411):   "Nif": "123456789Q",

12-28 20:10:25.809: I/System.out(1411):   "Razon": "BENITO TOCAMELA UNRATO",

12-28 20:10:25.809: I/System.out(1411):   "Nombre": "",

12-28 20:10:25.809: I/System.out(1411):   "Via": "",

12-28 20:10:25.809: I/System.out(1411):   "Calle": "",

12-28 20:10:25.809: I/System.out(1411):   "Num_calle": "0",

12-28 20:10:25.809: I/System.out(1411):   "Piso": "",

12-28 20:10:25.809: I/System.out(1411):   "Resto_domi": "",

12-28 20:10:25.809: I/System.out(1411):   "Cod_pos": "00000",

12-28 20:10:25.809: I/System.out(1411):   "Poblacion": "",

12-28 20:10:25.809: I/System.out(1411):   "Provincia": "",

12-28 20:10:25.809: I/System.out(1411):   "Tel1": "",

12-28 20:10:25.819: I/System.out(1411):   "Tel2": "",

12-28 20:10:25.819: I/System.out(1411):   "Tel3": "",

12-28 20:10:25.819: I/System.out(1411):   "Fax": ""

12-28 20:10:25.819: I/System.out(1411): }
```

So far so good I think. But when I deserialize it to obtain an object this is the output:

```
12-28 20:10:25.829: I/System.out(1411): ########GSON DESERIALIZATION: null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null
```

For some reason, it is taking all the atributes as null, however they are not.

The code in the c# side:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(propietario, Formatting.Indented);
```

I even tried without specifying format.

The code in the android side:

```
    System.out.println("########INPUT STRING: "+s);

    propietario = gson.fromJson(s, Propietario.class);

    System.out.println("########GSON DESERIALIZATION: "+propietario.toString());
```

Any suggestion??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does your `Propietario.class` class look like?

Comment: my tip, use gson to serialize an object, and check that output to see how it differs from your original input.

Comment: @blazsolar this is my class: http://pastebin.com/r9BnHr1i

Comment: @SynerCoder I will have dinner and then I will code that test.

Comment: So fields in class begin with lower case letter, but in JSON they are with upper case letter. Name of the field should be the same as it is in JSON. If you can't do that you should check [FieldNamingPolicy](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html)

Comment: @blazsolar you are right! I already thought it was a normal effect in json parsing but it seems there are some different policies to generate it. Thanks a lot for your help.